# Class name is converted to lower case when java command is executed on Windows

Tags: java, windows

Class name is converted to lower case when java command is executed on Windows

```
C:\>java -classpath test.jar org.test.Server
Error: Could not find or load main class org.test.server
```

'org.test.Server' has been changed to 'org.test.server'.
Actually, there is Server Class, but ClassNotFoundException occurs.

I have installed several versions of java, but the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Weird. The 'Gordian knot solution' - make an executable jar then you can do `java -jar test.jar`

Comment: -jar option working normally, also -classpath working on powershell normally.
bit if i use -classpath on cmd , occur problem...
actually ... i found this problem , when i build project on intellij..

Comment: Funnily enough - I was going to say try Powershell ;)

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem. I can use powershell, but the same error occurs when I build the project in intellij.

Comment: I thought you just said what I mentioned *did* solve it? ;) I'm hoping your posted command input and output is 100% correct? If so, that shouldn't occur, I don't think, *whatever* IntelliJ has done to your jar

Comment: It seems that something is being manipulated in the security program. The problem is now solved. thanks.